# Gulp AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: , how to specify task function?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am leaning Golang from [gorestful](https://github.com/narenaryan/gorestful/tree/master/chapter1).

I am trying to reproduce this project on my Ubuntu 18.04.

If I go for

```
gulp
```

from command line
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/home/milenko/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/home/milenko/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/milenko/go/src/github.com/MilenkoM/gulpfile.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

How to solve this?

```
gulp -v
[19:51:51] CLI version 3.9.1
[19:51:51] Local version 4.0.0
```

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

// This compiles new binary with source change
gulp.task("install-binary", shell.task([
  'go install github.com/MilenkoM/romanserver'
]));

// Second argument tells install-binary is a deapendency for restart-supervisor
gulp.task("restart-supervisor", ["install-binary"],  shell.task([
  'supervisorctl restart myserver'
]))

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // Watch the source code for all changes
  gulp.watch("*", ['install-binary', 'restart-supervisor']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

My tree

```
~/go/src/github.com/MilenkoM$ tree .
.
├── gulpfile.js
├── romanNumerals
│   └── data.go
└── romanserver
    └── main.go
```

Comment: We will need to see your gulpfile.js.

Comment: Take a look at my edit,please.

Comment: Please take a look at several questions here about migrating from gulp3 to gulp4.  You are using gulp3 syntax like "gulp.task('default', ['watch']);  That should be "gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));"  And similar change to your "restart-supervisor' task.